# Does R garbage collector frees memory allocated in C when using a R wrapper?

Tags: c, r, memory, memory-leaks

I am using a R wrapper for C code. Over small runs everything seemed to go fine but I ran longer analyses this week-end and I got what I think is a memory leak issue. I received the message:

> Mac OS X startup disk has no more space available for application memory and I had to restart the machine.

I am assuming I understand it correctly and I have a memory leak. Knowing how R and C manage memory will help me to understand where the memory leak is. My question is:

What happens to memory that has been allocated during the C run when the pointers are sent back to R? Is this memory freed by the R garbage collector or is it very important to make sure to free all memory in C directly?

**EDIT**

Some memory spaces have been allocated in R directly and passed to C. Those are the variables that are returned to R afterward and I suspect that R garbage collector will manage this memory correctly. The variables that I am suspecting might cause the memory leak are temporary variables which memory is allocated in C with either `malloc` or `calloc` and that are not returned to R.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how you allocated the memory, and I suspect the answer to your question is in [Writing R Extensions, Section 5.9.2 - Allocating Storage](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Allocating-storage), or [Section 6.1 - Memory Allocation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Memory-allocation).

Comment: I haven't checked your links yet. I tried to address your comment in an edit. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R garbage collector does not call C's `free` automatically unless you tell it.

For instance if you have a C function, let's call it "allocator" which returns a pointer with associated memory:

```
varA <- .Call("allocator", 1000)  #Allocate 1000 bytes
doProcess(varA) #...

varA <- .Call("allocator", 1000)  #Allocate 1000 bytes again
 #varA is overwritten, so R is going to try to call the object destructor
```

The problem is that there is no defined destructor for the "allocator" object. The way to do it is:

```
varA <- .Call("allocator", 1000)  #Allocate 1000 bytes
#let's tell R what to do in the garbage collection process:
reg.finalizer(varA, function(x){
                      .Call("deAllocator", x)
                      })
doProcess(varA) #...

varA <- .Call("allocator", 1000) #Allocate 1000 bytes again
#varA is overwritten, so R is going to call "deAllocator"
```

The "deAllocator" function has to be defined in C and it should free the memory from the pointer.